# Cannot read configmap with name: [xx] in namespace ['default'] Ignoring

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube, configmap

New to k8s.

Trying to read values from profile based config map. My configmap exists in default namespace. 
But, spring boot is not pickingup the values.

Config map looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01
data:
    application.properties: |-
        globalkey = global key value
    application-qa.properties: |-
        globalkey = global key qa value    
    application-prod.properties: |-
        globalkey = global key prod value
```

The config map is created in default namespace too.

```
kubectl get configmap -n default 

NAME                                  DATA   AGE
example-configmap-overriding-new-01   3      8d
```

My deployment file looks like

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
    name: demo-configmapk8testing
spec:  
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: demo-configmapk8testing
replicas: 1
template: 
    metadata:
        labels:
            app: demo-configmapk8testing        
    spec:
        containers:
          - name: demo-configmapk8testing
            image: Path to image
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            args: [
            "--spring.profiles.active=prod",
            "--spring.application.name=example-configmap-overriding-new-01",
            "--spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.name=example-configmap-
            overriding-new-01",
            "--spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.namespace=default",
            "--spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.enabled=true"]
            envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01
```

But the spring boot log says:-

```
2019-07-02 22:10:38.092  WARN 1 --- [           main] 
o.s.c.k.config.ConfigMapPropertySource   : Can't read configMap with name: 
[example-configmap-overriding-new-01] in namespace:[default]. Ignoring

2019-07-02 22:10:38.331  INFO 1 --- [           main] 
b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: 
CompositePropertySource {name='composite-configmap', propertySources= 
[ConfigMapPropertySource {name='configmap.example-configmap-overriding-new- 
01.default'}]}

2019-07-02 22:10:38.420  INFO 1 --- [           main] 
b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: 
SecretsPropertySource {name='secrets.example-configmap-overriding-new- 
01.default'}

2019-07-02 22:10:38.692  INFO 1 --- [           main] 
c.e.c.ConfigconsumerApplication          : **The following profiles are 
active: prod**

--some logs--

Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Could not resolve placeholder 
'globalkey' in value "${globalkey}"**
```

My spring boot config file looks like

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${globalkey}")
    private String globalkey;

    // with getter and setters 
}
```

My pom.xml has the following dependency too.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

I am running minikube in my local machine. Am I missing something here?

Could someone share some inputs here.

Answer (score 25):

**spring-cloud-kubernetes** doesn't have access to the Kubernetes API so it can't read the configMap. Check this docs for more details: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/security-service-accounts.adoc.

In short, apply this configuration and it will work fine:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: YOUR-NAME-SPACE
  name: namespace-reader
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
    resources: ["configmaps", "pods", "services", "endpoints", "secrets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

---

kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: namespace-reader-binding
  namespace: YOUR-NAME-SPACE
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: namespace-reader
  apiGroup: ""
```

You can read about Roles and RoleBinding in more detail here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/.

Note: You don't have to create volumes and volume mounts. I would say it is an alternative for it. If you would like to have it this way then you have to specify `spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.paths` in the spring boot application configuration (I have written it into **bootstrap.yaml** resource file).
E.g.

```
spring: 
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        paths: /etc/config/application.yaml
```

And then via Kubernetes Deployment configuration create ConfigMap volume and mount it on that path. In our example the path would be **/etc/config**.

Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: You just saved my day. This made my setup work (no Volume Mount... Spring Boot reading the ConfigMap directly, even a multiline Yaml file embeeded in it). Thanks.

Comment: is /etc/config default value for configmaps? i've created configmap, i can use in spring cloud kubernetes via consuming api. but when i want to use with mount, i dont know where is directory ?

Comment: This was very helpful! I simply kept paths as shown here, and configmap volumes were mounted to the same path

Answer (score 2):

the configmap manifest needs to be corrected. the format is incorrect

try this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01
data:
  application.properties: |
    globalkey=global-key-value
  application-qa.properties: |
    globalkey=global-key-qa-value
  application-prod.properties: |
    globalkey=global-key-prod-value
```

you should mount configmap as volume to use the config file in your application

```
          volumeMounts:
          - name: config
            mountPath: /config
        volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:        
            name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01
```

Comment: Hi @P Ekambaram. Thx for the reply. Still unlucky. Receiving same error. Any other idea? Thx.

Comment: Share your deployment yaml

Comment: Hi @P Ekambaram. Shared in question itself. Any clue?

Comment: Hi @P Ekambaram, Yes, also tried the vloume mount. But unlucky still.

Comment: get inside pod and see if the files are present under /config location

Comment: file would be mounted but change in the file will not be loaded unless we use spring cloud kubernetes project. right

Comment: you need to delete the pod so the new pod gets created using the updated configmap

Answer (score 2):

Just to drop a hint in case anybody face the same root cause as mine: https_proxy setting.

Our project has http/https_proxy within deployment config, and spring Kubernetes Client object was trying to reach master url by IP address to get configmaps.

While noproxy settings doesnt recognize wildcard char "*" (it must be v4 IPAddress), I have to set spring.cloud.kubernetes.client.masterUrl to kubernetes.default.svc so that it can be resolved by DNS name.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to mount your configmap also, may be that can help

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /app/config
  name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01

volumes:
- name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01
  configMap:
      name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01
```

Let me know please if it works.
Thanks

*Corrected syntax mistake*

Comment: Hi @Vipul: Thx for the reply. Tried but, receiving the same error as mentioned in the question. Any idea? Thx.