# Multi profile config map is not properly injected to container

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube, application.properties, configmap

New to k8s.

My configmap looks like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01
data:
    application.properties: |
        globalkey = global key value
        TeamName = Team Name value  
        #Some other key value pairs         
    application-qa.properties: |
        globalkey = global key qa value
        TeamName = Team Name qa value
        #Some other key value pairs
    application-prod.properties: |
        globalkey = global key prod value
        Company = company prod value
        #Some other key value pairs
```

While trying to use this config map in my spring boot application, app is not picking up the value from the configmap. 
It says,

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'globalkey' in value "${globalkey}"
```

**Posted that question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863782/cannot-read-configmap-with-name-xx-in-namespace-default-ignoring).**

Unfortunatly, saw the env varibles injected inside the container by the configmap. Shared the logs for reference.

```
application.properties=globalkey = global key value
TeamName = Team Name value
Purpose = Purpose value
RootFile = Root file value
Company = company value
Place = Place value
Country = Country value

application-prod.properties=globalkey = global key prod value
Company = company prod value
Place = Place prod value
Country = Country prod value

application-qa.properties=globalkey = global key qa value
TeamName = Team Name qa value
Purpose = Purpose qa value
RootFile = Root file qa value

#Some other key values pairs injected by k8s
```

I believe, from the logs, ***"application.properties=globalkey = global key value"***,  have not seen such key value pair.

Suspect, something went wrong in injecting the configmap. Is there any syntax mistake or?

PS:- I also tried the following syntax too.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01
data:
    application.properties: |-
        globalkey = global key value                    
    application-qa.properties: |-
        globalkey = global key qa value
```

I am using minikube for local development in windows 10 pro machine.

Could some one share insights here.

**PS: I am asking why env variable is displayed as "application.properties=globalkey = global key value" and I also linked the origin of the question. In old question, I asked like "cannot read from configmap". In new question, I asked like, "multi profile config map is not properly injected to container"**

Comment: The question is already answered in his previous question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863782/cannot-read-configmap-with-name-xx-in-namespace-default-ignoring

Using volumeMount with configmap is the solution as suggested in the above question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read configmap with name: \[xx\] in namespace \['default'\] Ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863782/cannot-read-configmap-with-name-xx-in-namespace-default-ignoring)

Comment: @Malathi: Thx for the comments. I have already tagged the "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863782/cannot-read-configmap-with-name-xx-in-namespace-default-ignoring" in this question. Both the old question and new question are different and the question which I asked in both place are different. I have got no answer for any of the question yet. 
"Using volumeMount with configmap is the solution as suggested in the above question" - This is not working and I commented the same.  Appreciate, to go through the question before downvoting! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax mistakes with your `ConfigMap`. Please, try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example-configmap-overriding-new-01
  namespace: <insert_namespace_here>
data:
  application.properties: |
    globalkey=global-key-value
    TeamName=Team-Name-value  
    #Some other key value pairs         
  application-qa.properties: |
    globalkey=global-key-qa-value
    TeamName=Team-Name-qa-value
    #Some other key value pairs
  application-prod.properties: |
    globalkey=global-key-prod-value
    Company=company-prod-value
    #Some other key value pairs
```

If you are not sure about your configuration, please see this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).
There are plenty of examples.

Please let me know if that helped.