# Can't read configMap with name: [XXXX] in namespace:[default]. Ignoring

Tags: spring, mongodb, kubernetes, minikube

I'm new in kuberntes.
I'm trying to deploy a spring boot application on my local machine with minikube. But i keep getting this error:
`Can't read configMap with name: [spring-mongo-service] in namespace:[default]. Ignoring.`
I'm using this pom file as configuration for spring boot application:

```
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Hoxton.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.piomin</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-discovery-ext</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Themain class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MongoExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MongoExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The configMap file is:

````
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
   name: mongo-conf
data:
 host: mongodb-service
 database: admin  ```
My secrets file is:
```apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
   name: mongo-secret
data:
  username: dGVzdA==
  password: dGVzdEAxMjM=
````

The data base deployement file is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mongo
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongo
  clusterIP: None  # We Use DNS, Thus ClusterIP is not relevant
    
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv-claim # name of PVC essential for identifying the storage data 
  labels:
    app: mongo
    tier: database
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce   #This specifies the mode of the claim that we are trying to create.
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi    #This will tell kubernetes about the amount of space we are trying to claim.
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
      name: mongodb-service

      
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo:latest
        name: mongo
        
        env:
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongo-secret
                key: username
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongo-secret
                key: password
                          
                
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          name: mongo                
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data/db #This is the path in the container on which the mounting will take place.
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-persistent-storage # Obtaining 'vloume' from PVC
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-pv-claim
```

The database pod is working perfectly
And the spring deployement file is:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: spring-mongo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: spring-mongo-service
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    nodePort: 30081
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spring-mongo-service
spec:
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: spring-mongo-service
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-mongo-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spring-mongo-service
          image: damdoum97/mongoed:latest 
          imagePullPolicy: Always 
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: MONGO_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-secret
                  key: username
            - name: MONGO_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-secret
                  key: password
            - name: MONGO_DB
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-conf  
                  key: database
            - name: MONGO_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-conf 
                  key: host
```

the application.yml file is:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-mongo-service
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: '${MONGO_HOST}'
      database: '${MONGO_DB}'
      port: 27017
      username: '${MONGO_USERNAME}'
      password: '${MONGO_PASSWORD}'
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      discovery:
        register: true
      secrets:
        name: mongo-secret

      config:
        enabled: true
        sources:
          - namespace: default
            name: mongo-conf
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: polling
        period: 1000
management:
  endpoint:
    restart:
      enabled: true
    health:
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true
```

Am I missing something here? Am I using the right dependencies ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read configmap with name: \[xx\] in namespace \['default'\] Ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863782/cannot-read-configmap-with-name-xx-in-namespace-default-ignoring)

Comment: No, I tried it and didn't work

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a secret with name: "spring-mongo-service". The only yaml file you provided is called "mongo-conf".

Comment: The deplyement file of spring application contains a service with this name

Comment: But why is is trying to access service as if it was a configMap: `Can't read configMap with name: [spring-mongo-service]`. spring-mongo-service is a service, not configmap. What am I missig here?

Comment: @Matt I've just added th application file to my question. Yes, I'can't figure why it's loking for spring-mongo-service as a configMap.